# Scala Rank-1 Polymorphism

Tags: scala

The following code snippet is from twitter's Scala school:

> Scala has rank-1 polymorphism. Roughly, this means that there are some type concepts you’d like to express in Scala that are “too generic” for the compiler to understand. Suppose you had some function:
>
> ```
> def toList[A](a: A) = List(a)
> ```
>
> which you wished to use generically:
>
> ```
> def foo[A, B](f: A => List[A], b: B) = f(b)
> ```
>
> This does not compile, because all type variables have to be fixed at the invocation site. Even if you “nail down” type `B`,
>
> ```
> def foo[A](f: A => List[A], i: Int) = f(i) // Line 1
> ```
>
> …you get a type mismatch.

Why would Line 1 fail? The type of B is known. Why should that fail compilation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scala> def toList[A](a:A) = List(a)
toList: [A](a: A)List[A]

scala> def foo[A, B](f: A => List[A], b: B) = f(b)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : b.type (with underlying type B)
 required: A
       def foo[A, B](f: A => List[A], b: B) = f(b)
```

This line doesn't compile because you are passing a value of type `B` when the function expects a value of type `A`.

```
def foo[A](f: A => List[A], i: Int) = f(i) // Line 1
```

For this line you will need to supply an implicit conversion from type `Int` to type `A`.